# This in ngModel

Tags: angular, typescript, conventions

I have noticed that in my angular application there are usages of

`[(ngModel)]="this.properties.offerValue"` and `[(ngModel)]="properties.offerValue"`

Both of them seem to work the same, my curiosity raised a question, is there any difference, and which is the correct usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 2+ supports both options for two way data binding. If you pass this refers to host component class. If not passed, that will internally refer to same component class.

**Preferred way :**

```
[(ngModel)]="properties.offerValue"
```

Answer (score 1):

As per official angular documentation:

[Angular-Docs-Template Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax)

There is no difference between

> [(ngModel)]="this.properties.offerValue" and
>   [(ngModel)]="properties.offerValue"

But preferred way to use

> [(ngModel)]="properties.offerValue"